# Generation of free running list of lapse rate and guess rate for psychometric curve fitting (Scipy)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

As a new user to the curve fitting function from scipy and a relatively new user of python, I am a little confused as to what *popt and p0 exactly generates (with reference to [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html))

So I am trying to plot a psychometric fitting here based of a customized sigmoid function formula that accounts for a guess and lapse rate (Both with values between 0 and 1 to account for participant guessing and performance lapse rates in an experiment. These values would define the fit on the lower and upper end of the curve fit respectively.)

I can get the function to generate the best lapse rate it could fit to the curve when a fixed guess rate was set outside the function. But when I want the function to generate both the best lapse rate and guess rate, it couldn't, and gave the following error:-

> File "C:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 447, in _general_function
>       return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
>   TypeError: sigmoidscaled() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)*

Now I am aware that this means that there was no value coming from the 'guess rate' variable and thus this error. So how is it that the function was able to generate a 'lapse rate' but not a 'guess rate' here?

These are the codes when the guess rate is a prefixed value and the curve fit is successful:-

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

n = 20 #20 trials
ydata = [0/n, 9.0/n, 9.0/n, 14.0/n, 17.0/n] #Divided by n to fit to a plot of y =1
xdata = np.array([ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

guess = 0.05 #Set the minimum chance level

#The scaled sigmoid function
def sigmoidscaled(x, x0, k, lapse):
    F = (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) 
    z = guess + (1-guess-lapse)/F
    return z

p0=[1,1,-10] 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ydata, p0, maxfev = 3000)

#Start and End of x-axis, in spaces of n. The higher the n, the smoother the curve.
x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
#The sigmoid values along the y-axis, generated in relation to the x values and the 50% point.
y = sigmoidscaled(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='Psychometric Raw', color = 'blue')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='Psychometric Fit', color = 'blue')
#y axis range.
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
#Replace x-axis numbers as labels and y-axis numbers as percentage
xticks([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], ['C1','CN2','N3','CN4','S5'])
yticks([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], ['0%','20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
pylab.legend(loc='best')
xlabel('Conditions')
ylabel('% perceived more sin like')
pylab.show()
```

Whereas when I tried to have the formula try to find the best 'guess' value, it couldn't. (Here, 'guess = 0.05 #Set the minimum chance level' was removed and a guess variable inserted into the sigmoid function.) :-

```
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

n = 20 #20 trials
ydata = [0/n, 9.0/n, 9.0/n, 14.0/n, 17.0/n] #Divided by n to fit to a plot of y =1
xdata = np.array([ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])


#The scaled sigmoid function
def sigmoidscaled(x, x0, k, lapse, guess):
    F = (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) 
    z = guess + (1-guess-lapse)/F
    return z

p0=[1,1,-10] 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ydata, p0, maxfev = 3000)

#Start and End of x-axis, in spaces of n. The higher the n, the smoother the curve.
x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
#The sigmoid values along the y-axis, generated in relation to the x values and the 50% point.
y = sigmoidscaled(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='Psychometric Raw', color = 'blue')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='Psychometric Fit', color = 'blue')
#y axis range.
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
#Replace x-axis numbers as labels and y-axis numbers as percentage
xticks([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], ['C1','CN2','N3','CN4','S5'])
yticks([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], ['0%','20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
pylab.legend(loc='best')
xlabel('Conditions')
ylabel('% perceived more sin like')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p0` is the starting point for the fit procedure. `popt` is the resulting best-fit values of the parameters.

Note that `curve_fit` assumes that the signature of your function if `f(x, *parameters)`: the first argument is an independent variable for which you have `xdata`, and the rest are parameters that you want optimized.

In your first example, `sigmoidscaled` takes four arguments, and you provide a length-three list for `p0`. This way, the fitting starts with `x0 = 1; k = 1; lapse = -10`.

In your second example, `sigmoidscaled` takes five arguments, meaning you're fitting four parameters for which you need initial values.

Quick check:

```
In [22]: p0 = [1, 1, -10, 0]    # add the 4th element

In [23]: popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ydata, p0, maxfev = 3000)

In [24]: popt
Out[24]: array([ -1.97865387e+01,   3.31731590e-01,  -1.03275740e-01,
        -1.05595226e+03])
```

Comment: Oh right thanks! Just one more question - As I need to constrain the values of lapse and guess rate to values between 0 and 1 (Ie. the 3rd and 4th element in p0), is there a way to specify this condition somehow?

Comment: Yes, there is, if you're using SciPy 0.17 or above, see the docs for the `bounds` argument