# Sigmoidal curve fit, how to get the value of x when y=0.5

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve the following function so that after fitting, I want to get the value of `x` when `y=0.5`.

The function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, b, c):
    y = 1 / (1 + c*np.exp(-b*x))
    return y

x_data = [4, 6, 8, 10]
y_data = [0.86, 0.73, 0.53, 0.3]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data,(28.14,-0.25))
```

please explain how would you carry out this using python!
Thanks!

Comment: where is `curve_fit` coming from?

Comment: @piRSquared It's `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generation of free running list of lapse rate and guess rate for psychometric curve fitting (Scipy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044905/generation-of-free-running-list-of-lapse-rate-and-guess-rate-for-psychometric-cu)

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I get a warning, and `popt` is the same as your initial guess,  `(28.14, -0.25)`. If you try plotting this you'll see that it's essentially a straight line at `y == 1` that doesn't fit your data well at all:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(4, 10, 1000)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=50, zorder=20)
ax.plot(x, y, '-k', lw=2)
```

[image]

The problem is that you're initializing with a negative value for the `b` parameter. Remember that `b` gets negated, so you're actually exponentiating `x` times a *positive* number, which blows up your denominator. Instead you want to initialize with a *positive* value for `b`, but perhaps a negative value for `c` (to give you your negative slope):

```
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data, (-0.5, 0.1))
y2 = sigmoid(x, *popt2)

ax.plot(x, y2, '-r', lw=2)
```

[image]

---

To get the value of `x` at `y == 0.5` using nonlinear optimization you need to define an objective function, which could be the square of the difference between `0.5` and `sigmoid(x, b, c)`:

```
def objective(x, b, c):
    return (0.5 - sigmoid(x, b, c)) ** 2
```

You can then use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) or [`scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html) to find the value of `x` that minimizes the objective function:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

res = minimize_scalar(objective, bracket=(4, 10), args=tuple(popt2))
ax.annotate("$y = 0.5$", (res.x, 0.5), (30, 30), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05), fontsize='x-large')
```

[image]